# Are there methods to solve a system of coupled integral equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I was wondering if there were methods to solve a system of coupled integral equations. The example case I am thinking about is

$$f(x)=g(x)+\int_a^xf(x^\prime)h(x^\prime) dx^\prime$$

$$h(x)=k(x)+\int_b^x l(x^\prime)h(x^\prime) dx^\prime $$

where g, k, and l are known functions and h and f are unknown. Any suggestions on where to look, or alternative methods for this type of system would be great!

Comment: do you know any methods of solving this kind of equation for uncoupled vector-valued functions? (in this case you can transform your system)

Comment: Take derivatives everywhere, and get an ODE?

Comment: Start with the second one and plug the solution into the first one?

Comment: Indeed, take the derivatives and then use the method of variation of constants.